# Simulating a wp page - wp page load sequence

Tags: plugins, pages

I'm toying with a honeypot to catch form spammers.  I've hidden a link to a non-existent page in the footer.  What I'm attempting to do now is, when they visit that link, to display a form that looks to be a normal WP page for that site.  What I have below does that with one exception.  I'm getting a lot CORS errors No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' errors.  So apparently I'm missing something in the wp loading sequence to display a page.  Pages loaded the normal way on the site do not display this CORS error.

I've tried adding

```
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

without success.

Any ideas?

```
    add_action('parse_request', array($this, 'Check_Incoming'));

    public function Check_Incoming() {
        global $wp;
        $current_url = add_query_arg($wp->query_string, '', home_url($wp->request));
        $parsed = parse_url($current_url);
        if ($parsed['path'] == '/myhiddenform') {
            include_once 'My_Request.php';
            $form = new Form_Show();            
            get_header();
            wp_head();
            $form->show_form();
            get_footer();
            wp_footer();
            die();
        }
    }
```

Here's the exact errors I'm getting. All seem to be trying to load fontawesome webfonts..

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED   fontawesome-webfont.ttf:1 

Access to font at 'https://example.com/wp-content/themes/melos/lib/extentions/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0' from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: So the hidden URL looks like `https://example.com/myhiddenform`? And `wp_head()` is normally called in the header template, so it's kinda weird you're doing `get_header(); wp_head();`.. same goes with the `get_footer(); wp_footer();`..

Comment: Yea, I started with wp_head and wp_footer. They didn't include the template so I added them back in after I found get_header did hoping I'd missed something but I didn't notice any difference.  Still had the CORS error.  And yes, the actual link to the hidden form looks like <a href="https://example.com/myhiddenform/" /></a> with the theory that bots will find it. I just echo that out in a wp_footer hook. Somewhere in the parsing the trailing slash gets stripped.

Comment: Well, looks like stack exchange stripped a lot of that url out. It has https:// and a trailing slash.

Comment: How did you find out about the CORS errors? If you do `if ($parsed['path'] == '/myhiddenform') { echo 'test'; die(); }`, are you still getting the same errors? Have you tried clearing your caches and disabling caching just for a while?

Comment: I found them by checking the Chrome console because something didn't look quite right.  I've added the exact error (url changed) to the OP.  And no, I'm not getting those errors with just an echo. They're all coming from the headers it's trying to load.  The one in the OP is trying to load fontawesome from the theme directory.

Comment: I THINK I've found the problem.  The font is located at example.com/path and the origin is apparently www.example.com/path.  I was using www.example.com/path to access it and I'm guessing the browser is seeing the www as a subdomain.  Since it's not in the .htaccess, it's blocking it as being cross domain, which is damned silly.  As soon as I got chrome to actually use example.com without the www, the errors went away.

Thanks for helping me noodle through this! This was not the solution I was expecting.  I was sure there was some wp event I was failing to load.

Comment: Now, why it's blocking just the fontawesome and not any of the css or js, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

> So apparently I'm missing something in the wp loading sequence to
> display a page.

Not exactly, or that your code is good in terms of parsing the request.

And I don't know why you need the `add_query_arg()` below, but this:

```php
public function Check_Incoming() {
    global $wp;
    $current_url = add_query_arg($wp->query_string, '', home_url($wp->request));
    $parsed = parse_url($current_url);
    if ($parsed['path'] == '/myhiddenform') {
```

Could be simplified like so:

```php
public function Check_Incoming( $wp ) {
    if ( 'myhiddenform' === $wp->request ) {
```

### Now here's why are you getting the CORS error

1. Font Awesome uses [web fonts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Web_fonts) (loaded via `@font-face`), and web font requests are subject to the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy); and
2. You accessed the page with the `www` prefix (`https://www.example.com/myhiddenform`) and yet the web font URL did not have that prefix (`https://example.com/.../fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0`), which means the hostname didn't match, i.e. `www.example.com` and `example.com` do not match — yes, they actually pointed to the same domain, but in CORS context, they are different.

   And because the resource did not have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, then that consequently caused the browser to not load the font and instead throw the CORS error.

### How to solve the problem

Any of these would work, but you should use functions like `get_template_directory_uri()` to output the link to your CSS file.

- The CORS error says, `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`, hence just set the header on the requested web font. :)

  I.e. Make sure the server sets the header when the `example.com/.../fontawesome-webfont.ttf` (with or without the `www`) is requested.

  And with `.htaccess`, you can do it like so ([credits to this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5009126)):

  ```
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
      <IfModule mod_headers.c>
          Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
      </IfModule>
  </FilesMatch>
  ```
- Redirect all requests to `www.example.com/*` to `example.com/*`, or vice-versa depending on your [canonical domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Choosing_between_www_and_non-www_URLs#so_do_i_have_to_choose_one_or_the_other_for_my_web_site), i.e. whether your "*Site Address (URL)*" setting has the `www` prefix or not.

  And with `.htaccess`, you can do it like so ([credits to this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54313390)):

  ```
  # Add at the top in your .htaccess file. I.e. Above the BEGIN WordPress line.
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#%{HTTPS}s ^www\.(.+?)\.?#(?:on(s)|)
      RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
  </IfModule>
  ```

  But actually, WordPress has a [`redirect_canonical()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/redirect_canonical/) function which will do the above redirection, however, that won't happen in your case since the function is hooked onto `template_redirect` which runs after (but not immediately after) the [`parse_request` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_request/).

### Another possible solution

- Use absolute path (i.e. without the domain) when linking to your (Font Awesome) CSS files.

  So for example:

  ```html
  <!-- Use this: -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/melos/.../your-file.css" />

  <!-- And not this: -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/wp-content/themes/melos/.../your-file.css" />
  ```

  But in WordPress, CSS files should be loaded using `wp_enqueue_style()`, and although you can use absolute paths, WordPress will actually turn the URL into a fully-qualified one (with the domain) when WordPress generates the `<link>` tag, hence the same problem would still happen.

  Therefore you should just set the CORS header, or redirect the `www` to non-`www` (or vice-versa), or both.

### Additional Notes

- When outputting the hidden link, you should use WordPress functions like `home_url()` like so: `<a href="<?php echo home_url( '/myhiddenform/' ); ?>">...</a>`.